# Combine similar rows in a file using AWK

Tags: linux, bash, awk, gawk

again!
Can somebody help me with next question:

I need to combine similar rows in a file using awk. Example
*File has next rows:*

```
Mike dollar 15  
Fred euro 10  
Mike euro 4  
Fred euro 4
```

*Output should look like:*

```
Mike:   
dollar 15  
euro 4  

Fred:  
euro 14
```

How do I combine similar patterns in different rows into one row?
Thanks a lot for ideas!

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{a[$1,$2]+=$3; k1s[$1]; k2s[$2]} 
    END{for(k1 in k1s) 
          {print k1":"; 
           for(k2 in k2s) if(a[k1,k2]) print k2, a[k1,k2]; print ""}}' file

Mike:
euro 4
dollar 15

Fred:
euro 14
```